# Checkboxes in ListActivity seem to be linked; why? How do I fix it?

Tags: android, android-layout, adapter, listactivity

I have an activity which inherits ListActivity, and shows a list populate via an XML layout and a custom adapter class. It all renders fine, and as expected. The row XML includes in it a checkbox.

Now, what's weird is that the checkboxes seem to be linked every so many rows. That is, if I check the checkbox in row 0, then it also checks the checkboxes in rows 8, 18, 28, 38, 48, etc.

Why would this be, and how can I fix it?

If it is pertinent, i **am** reusing the view passed into my adapter when it is available. It does also seem that when I scroll one of the checked ones to the top of the screen, the next one to be checked is the second one off the bottom of the screen.

Below is my `getView` code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.contacts_row, null);
    }

    cb.GroupMembership.moveToPosition(position);
    long cid = cb.GroupMembership.getLong(0);
    String clk = cb.GroupMembership.getString(1);
    String cnm = cb.GroupMembership.getString(2);
    long pid = cb.GroupMembership.getLong(3);

    ImageView bdg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactBadge);
    Uri pic = GroupsLib.getContactPhotoUri(pid);
    if (pic == null) {
        bdg.setImageResource(R.drawable.contactg);
    } else {
        bdg.setImageURI(pic);
    }

    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName)).setText(cnm);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Post your adapter (`getView`) code, but, in all likelihood, it's a View recycling problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reuse your view you should actually set the state of all controls in it (so basically clean-up). Precisely because it is reused.

Usually it would look like (in adapter):

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SomeObject obj = getDataFromYourModel(position);
    if (convertView == null) { 
        convertView = ....; //inflate view here
    } 

    setMyViewParameters(obj,convertView);
}

public void setMyViewParameters(SomeObject obj, View view) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);

    cb.setChecked(obj.isChecked);
    //other initialisation
}
```

This way, you always reset the values when the view is reused.

Comment: Hmmm... okay. I will do something along these lines and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Okay... I didn't set the checkboxes to the actual value I want yet, but set it to `false` for now, and that fixed it. Thanks to your point-out, I see now how this works with the way Android is geared towards "instant-save" methodology. Just wasn't thinking that way. Thanks!

Comment: Quick update... tied my checkboxes up to a procedure to get their actual checked values, and now it works perfectly! Cheers!!  :)